# How do I append a unique menu ID to the menu?

Tags: 7, routes

I'm using Drupal 7 and I want to append a unique ID to specific menus. My search result gives me the way to change the item of the menu, but I want to change the menu itself. 
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935477/how-to-theme-a-menu-block-in-drupal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty way:

Go to your themes directory and open up page.tpl.php. I'm using a Zen based theme and I have the following code which will print the secondary menu:

```
     <?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
       'links' => $secondary_menu,
       'attributes' => array(
       'id' => 'secondary-menu',
       'class' => array('links', 'clearfix'),
      ),
      'heading' => array(
        'text' => $secondary_menu_heading,
        'level' => 'h2',
        'class' => array('element-invisible'),
      ),
    )); ?>
```

That can simply be edited to (modified line has asterisks):

```
     <?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
       'links' => $secondary_menu,
       'attributes' => array(
       ***'id' => array('secondary-menu', 'my-new-id'),***
       'class' => array('links', 'clearfix'),
      ),
      'heading' => array(
        'text' => $secondary_menu_heading,
        'level' => 'h2',
        'class' => array('element-invisible'),
      ),
    )); ?>
```

**Edit:**

I don't really understand you when you say you're having trouble with the multi-dimensional menus and languages, but if you need more control, why not use theme_menu_tree? Override that in your theme's template.tpl.php with something like:

```
function my_theme_name_menu_tree($variables) {
  if ($variables['some_condition_you_care_about'])
    return '<ul class="menu" id="my_custom_id">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
  else
    return '<ul class="menu">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: i think your code doing same as 
`print theme('links', array('links' => menu_navigation_links('primary-links'), 'attributes' => array('id'=> array('myid')) ));`
but the problem is the menu is multi dimensional and is in 2 languages and this function does not get the menu translated or with multi dimensions

Comment: by the way 
what is the function that provide $links ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the menu [attributes module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) to add custom classes, id's, names etc... to any menu item in Drupal. Very handy module when you are looking to alter Drupal's menu system to create a custom look.

Comment: yes i know that module well ,
but it gives attributes to the menu items not the menu itself
i need to assign an id to the basic menu.

Comment: sorry i miss read it as menu item. you can use [theme_menu_tree()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution maybe you'd consider using the [Menu block module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block). You use it to create blocks for specific menus, with custom depth ranges, starting item etc.

I think I use it for every menu in my site now as I love having that control AND **as an added bonus it will add your unique IDs to each menu.**

Answer (score 0):

In order to theme the unordered list, you need to call theme_menu_tree(). You can edit your template.php in order to call this.

```
function THEMENAME_menu_tree__MENUNAME($variables){
  return '<ul class="your-custom-class" id="your-custom-id">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

Then, if you want to theme your links, call theme_menu_link().

```
function THEMENAME_menu_link__MENUNAME($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

Now, the problem with Drupal 7 is that there is a major bug when it comes to displaying the active trail of custom menus.

See issue
[Issue #520106 - No way to dynamically set active trail](http://drupal.org/node/520106)
[Issue #942782 - Custom menus never receive an active trail](http://drupal.org/node/942782)

You are basically out of luck if you want some true custom menus. These issues are very long standing in the drupal community so I am not sure if they will be fixed anytime soon. I don't know if there is some PHP that can help with it. You can turn to some alternative modules in order to help ease functionaltiy, like [Menu Attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) and [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block). They both can help get around the cruddy menu system in Drupal 7.