# How to theme a menu block?

Tags: 7, routes, theming

I have created a custom menu (lets call it "mynav") and in my theme I've created a template specifically for it (`block--menu--menu-mynav.tpl.php`) which contains:

```
<div id="mynav" class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print $content ?>
</div>
```

This works fine.

However I'd prefer to apply the id to the unordered list that is generated and contained in `$content`. I guess I need to create a function `MYTHEME_links__system_mynav_menu` like this:

```
function MYTHEME_links__system_mynav_menu($variables) {
  return "TEST"; // Generate HTML here (<ul id="mynav">...)
}
```

but it doesn't seem to have an affect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is likely a duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2258/how-do-i-append-a-unique-menu-id-to-the-menu/7666

Comment: The other question is about adding a unique menu ID, while this question is more generic.

Comment: Exact question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935477/how-to-theme-a-menu-block-in-drupal

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In order to theme the unordered list, you need to call theme_menu_tree(). You can edit your template.php in order to call this.

```
function THEMENAME_menu_tree__MENUNAME($variables){
  return '<ul class="your-custom-class" id="your-custom-id">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

Then, if you want to theme your links, call theme_menu_link().

```
function THEMENAME_menu_link__MENUNAME($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

Now, the problem with Drupal 7 is that there is a major bug when it comes to displaying the active trail of custom menus.

See issue
[Issue #520106 - No way to dynamically set active trail](http://drupal.org/node/520106)
[Issue #942782 - Custom menus never receive an active trail](http://drupal.org/node/942782)

You are basically out of luck if you want some true custom menus. These issues are very long standing in the drupal community so I am not sure if they will be fixed anytime soon. I don't know if there is some PHP that can help with it. You can turn to some alternative modules in order to help ease functionaltiy, like [Menu Attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) and [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block). They both can help get around the cruddy menu system in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your theme's template.php, this was the way to do things in Drupal 6

```
function MYTHEME_links__system_mynav_menu($variables) {
  return "TEST"; // Generate HTML here (<ul id="mynav">...)
}
```

In Drupal 7 you need to call

```
  function MYTHME_menu_link(array $variables) {

  }
```

Comment: `MYTHEME_menu_link` seems to only handle the individual links. I can't reach the `ul`.

Comment: I'm looking into it,  I don't know if you can anymore.   I know with Drupal 7 you have more power over the links, but less power over the menus.