# Theming a menu - removing a whitespace between the last <li> and <ul>

Tags: theming, routes

I want to alter the HTML of the main menu. I have a manu set up with text-align: justify.
Now in Chrome, the whitespace between the last `li` and `ul` is rendered as 4px, making the last item not aligned to the right margin. See this [stackexchange post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638222/text-align-justify-on-horizontal-menu-remove-the-added-space-on-the-right). I want to remove the whitespace or replace it with and html comment.
I am a bit lost ;-). What should I be overriding? `theme_menu_tree`?
I am using the Omega 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it sounds like your question is really about how to manipulate the main menu markup in Omega, I guess I'll focus on that. That said however, the "whitespace" issue from the post that you reference is quit strange, as I'm not sure I understand how a newline between an closing `li` and `ul` tag would influence any visible alignment behavior. I'm also not sure that Omega even adds any such newlines to the menu output by default. Still, it sounds like you've isolated this as a cause already.

If you are using the main menu that's automatically inserted within the page by Omega (as opposed to displaying your main menu via a menu block or similar), then I believe the most specific theme hook that applies is 'links__system_main_menu'. Check out the omega/omega/templates/region--menu.tpl.php theme file to see how this is ultimately called.

It's important to note however that 'links__system_main_menu' is not necessarily a hook that you'll find an existing theme function for, it's just a suggested pattern. See [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15652/where-is-links-system-main-menu-defined) for more on that. Chances are the theme function that's actually getting used currently is `theme_links()`, or in the case of Omega (which already has an override setup) `omega_links()`.

So if you want to target an override that's *specific* to just the main menu you could use the code from `omega_links()` as a template for your own override called `MYTHEMENAME_links__system_main_menu()`. Then within this new function you could adjust the output to tweak the way "whitespace" is added before and after any `ul` and `li` tags as you deem necessary.

Comment: wow, thanks for such an extensive answer. I'll be working that out very soon.

Comment: I'm trying to apply your suggestions. It uses the `omega_links` function from `omega.theme.inc`. I copied the code from that function to `MYTHEME_links()` in the template.php of my file and it's being overridden. So far so good...

Comment: ...but the main menu that goes through blocks (not rendered automatically by means of primary / secondary links) does not go through that 'theme_links' function...

Comment: Yeah, for a menu in a block the theme stuff is a bit different. For that I think the hook that applies is 'menu_link'. See [this post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7274/how-to-theme-a-menu-block) for more on that. That might actually make more sense within the context of this problem as the default `theme_menu_link()` puts a newline (`\n`) after each `li`, which would seem to correlate with the core issue you have identified. So if you override that function you might just have to remove the `\n` part.