# How do I theme (add extra markup to) menu links in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, theming, routes

I have a secondary menu that displays like:

```
<ul class="secondarynav">
<li class="menu-428 first">
<a href="/content/page">PAGE</a>
</li>
...
```

I would like to change that so it displays a `<span>` on the links like:

```
<ul class="secondarynav">
<li class="menu-428 first">
<a href="/content/page"><span>PAGE</span></a>
</li>
...
```

According to the [Drupal 7 theme_menu_link documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) and this answer on [theming Drupal 7 menu links](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2258/how-do-i-append-a-unique-menu-id-to-the-menu/7666#7666), I should just be able to declare a hook like `THEMENAME_menu_link__MENUNAME($variables)`.

I've declared the following two functions in my `template.php`, but neither of them is being called:

```
function MYTEMPLATE_menu_link__system_secondary_menu(array $variables) {die;}
function MYTEMPLATE_menu_link__secondary_menu(array $variables) {die;}
```

I'm using Framework, and there's a section like:

```
if (isset($vars['secondary_menu'])) {
    $vars['secondary_menu'] = theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
        'links' => $vars['secondary_menu'],
        'attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('secondaryNavigation'),
    )
    ));
}
```

What's the cleanest / best practice-y way of printing an extra `<span>` in the menu links for this menu only?

I can write a function to theme the entire menu at once with `function MYTEMPLATE_links__system_secondary_menu(array $variables)`, but theming the entire menu  just to get a `<span>` in each link seems like overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It calls `theme('links__system_secondary_menu')`. By default, there is no `theme_links__system_secondary_menu`, so I guess it is calling [theme_links](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_links/7). Looking at the function, all you have to do is copy it to your theme as `THEMENAME_links__system_secondary_menu`, then change the call to [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/7) to something like:

```
$link['html'] = TRUE;
$output .= l('<span class="whatever">' . $link['title'] . '</span>', $link['href'], $link);
```

The `html => true` is required or `l()` will strip the html out of its first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

For custom menus (created by you) the MENUNAME is the machine name of the menu (obtainable by visiting the menu edit page) with dashes converted to underscores. So for a menu called 'Secondary Menu' the machine name should be 'secondary-menu' (make sure to check) which converts to 'secondary_menu'. So you should implement THEMENAME_menu_link__secondary_menu(array $variables).